# How to push arrays of objects to create new array without merging object properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I am trying to save loop outputs into one array.
If I console.log(arr2) I got my wanted result but in more than one array. I want all that in one array.
When I'm trying to use .push all arrays results in the same values.

Maybe I can do this in some other way but I have no clue how.

```js
    let b = {};
    let arr3 = [];
    let arr1 = [{value1: 123, value2: 34, value3: 90, value4: 23, value5: 32},{value1: 10, value2: 09, value3: 54, value4: 32, value5: 311}];
    for (let a = 0; a <=4; a++){
       b = {"value1": a*a, "value3": a+12, "value4": a/2};
       arr2 = arr1.map(function(record){
       record.value1 = b.value1;
       record.value3 = b.value3;
       record.value4 = b.value4;
       return record;
       })
       // console.log(arr2);
       arr3.push(arr2);

}
console.log(arr3);
```

This is what I accomplish with .push and this is not what I want.

```
  [
  { value1: 0, value2: 34, value3: 12, value4: 0, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 0, value2: 9, value3: 12, value4: 0, value5: 311 }
]
[
  { value1: 1, value2: 34, value3: 13, value4: 0.5, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 1, value2: 9, value3: 13, value4: 0.5, value5: 311 }
]
[
  { value1: 4, value2: 34, value3: 14, value4: 1, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 4, value2: 9, value3: 14, value4: 1, value5: 311 }
]
[
  { value1: 9, value2: 34, value3: 15, value4: 1.5, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 9, value2: 9, value3: 15, value4: 1.5, value5: 311 }
]
[
  { value1: 16, value2: 34, value3: 16, value4: 2, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 16, value2: 9, value3: 16, value4: 2, value5: 311 }
]
```

When I console.log(arr2) inside the for-loop i got almost what I want, the wanted results but not in a single array.

```
   [
  { value1: 0, value2: 34, value3: 12, value4: 0, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 0, value2: 9, value3: 12, value4: 0, value5: 311 }
]
[
  { value1: 1, value2: 34, value3: 13, value4: 0.5, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 1, value2: 9, value3: 13, value4: 0.5, value5: 311 }
]
[
  { value1: 4, value2: 34, value3: 14, value4: 1, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 4, value2: 9, value3: 14, value4: 1, value5: 311 }
]
[
  { value1: 9, value2: 34, value3: 15, value4: 1.5, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 9, value2: 9, value3: 15, value4: 1.5, value5: 311 }
]
[
  { value1: 16, value2: 34, value3: 16, value4: 2, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 16, value2: 9, value3: 16, value4: 2, value5: 311 }
]
```

expected result:

```
[
  { value1: 0, value2: 34, value3: 12, value4: 0, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 0, value2: 9, value3: 12, value4: 0, value5: 311 },
  { value1: 1, value2: 34, value3: 13, value4: 0.5, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 1, value2: 9, value3: 13, value4: 0.5, value5: 311 },
  { value1: 4, value2: 34, value3: 14, value4: 1, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 4, value2: 9, value3: 14, value4: 1, value5: 311 },
  { value1: 9, value2: 34, value3: 15, value4: 1.5, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 9, value2: 9, value3: 15, value4: 1.5, value5: 311 },
  { value1: 16, value2: 34, value3: 16, value4: 2, value5: 32 },
  { value1: 16, value2: 9, value3: 16, value4: 2, value5: 311 }
]
```

Comment: `"value1": a^2` - I don't think that part does what you might think it does.

Comment: can you add your expected output

Comment: @Andreas thanks, but that part is not essential to my problem

Comment: It is, because you won't ever get the result you want with that operator...

Comment: @Andreas Ok, I changed it to a*a

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes, I have edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because objects work by reference. This should work :
    Replace this :

```
 arr2 = arr1.map(function(record){
   record.value1 = b.value1;
   record.value3 = b.value3;
   record.value4 = b.value4;
   return record;
   })
```

By this in your code :

```
 arr2 = arr1.map(function(record) {
const tempRecord = {...record}
tempRecord.value1 = b.value1;
tempRecord.value3 = b.value3;
tempRecord.value4 = b.value4;
return tempRecord;
})
```

You can accomplish the final result by doing this : 
   arr3.flat();

Comment: You are welcome. You can flatten the array if you want by doing this : `arr3.flat()`

Comment: Thanks again, perfect! now I'm on to the next challange :)